# How I can change the URI with ingress. app-root and rewrite-target not wok

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I have a problem with nginx Ingress. We have rules in different namespaces and test apps work fine.

Now we want to access a new application over the ingress, but for this one we need another URL rule:

f.e. Rule path: /app/app-function

Fortunately the app shows me the URI it gets. The App gets the Path from the ingress, I need to change it to something.
I try app-root and rewrite-target but I can not see any changes in the URI.

Pasting my `yaml` file below. Do you have any idea? I tried it in the master rule too, but nothing happend. But the master rule is in the ingress namespace...

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rule-app
  namespace: pilot
  annotations:
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "minion"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/test"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: "true"

spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - host: "Host"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app/app-function
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: new-app
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: you are mixing annotations.  [annotations that start with nginx.com are only supported with NGINX Plus.paid solution](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/#summary-of-annotations). `nginx.org` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io` is different things. Also have you checked official examples of rewrite https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite#examples ?

Comment: Thank you, I hve not see and not knowen that is importen. I will check if the  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io has a Function for Master/minion, too or nginx.org has a Function for redirect. 

After testing I will give a feedback. 

After testing I will give a feedback.

Comment: glad that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Vit, I found a solution with your tipp.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rule-app
  namespace: pilot
  annotations:
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "minion"
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=new-app rewrite=/test"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - host: "Host"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app/app-function
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: new-app
            port:
              number: 8080
```